# Send an Email with Attachment in Javascript

Tags: javascript, email, sendmail, attachment, email-attachments

is there a possibility to send an E-Mail via Javascript with an attachment?

I am using the "mailto@..." method which is working to send the Mail with a proper body and a subject, but I would like to send a file which is uploaded by the user via the `<input type="file">` HTML-tag.

Comment: Is this helpful? https://www.w3schools.com/nodejs/nodejs_email.asp

Comment: you can't do that with a mailto tag. This would require server-side code.

Comment: The Problem is, that the HTML (with all of it's inputs and forms to send the email) and the .js-files will be embeded into a webpage (made with jimdo). 
Is it possible to use node.js in that way.
And if not, does there exist another possibility beside the mailto tag?